# How to deal with diacritics in tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

According to the "[Which language should tags be in?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/which-language-should-tags-be-in)" question - most tags should be written in English.

But what about tags that are very specific to German? **How do you deal with diacritics** in those tags? Write normally and let the site convert it to ASCII equivalent (ä -> a) or transcribe yourself (ä -> ae etc.)?

Comment: Technical Note: The site currently ONLY supports ASCII tags. 
There will be some compromises of this nature until we can design a functional set of localization features. Creating a non-English site in on the Stack Exchange network is still a bit ground-breaking.

Answer (score 4):

As the author of a [WordPress plugin](https://github.com/toscho/Germanix-WordPress-Plugin/blob/master/germanix_url.php) that deals with such transliterations I can tell how difficult it is to get this right by software. I recommend not to rely on an algorithm.
It doesn’t take much time to do this manually, and the moderators will help. After a while the auto-correction will persuade newcomers to use the canonical form that has evolved for a tag.

Answer (score 4):

I think that it is important that Umlauts are supported in some way.

I just tried to introduce the tag "Fälle" and it was converted to "falle".

This is not optimal since the main point of the German tags is to entice new users to use existing tags, but they will not be convinced that "falle" is really meant to be "Fälle".

I support automatical conversion to ae, oe, ue, ss in tags, because there will also be users without German keyboards.

Comment: + capitalization should be maintained. Fälle is not fälle. The most prominent example would be Weg and weg, first is a route, second is away.

Comment: Samuel, you can adjust most keyboards to provide German diacritics with ALT + [letter] though.

Answer (score 0):

We Germans have no problem understanding the replacements ae, oe, ue.

In the early days of computing when there where only US-keybords, and we Germans had no problems to express ourselves without using the **Umlaute**.

I guess some hack lawyer having a name containg an Umlaut succeeed in not paying his taxes.
This forcing the tax office to cry to be able to print them.

Of course there are some esthetes (Schöngeister) who cry for them.

Personally I would prefer use an ASCII clean language and I regret that the US didn't keep them as spoils of war.