# Shouldn't umlauts be allowed on a site on German language?

Tags: bug, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Interface localization to German](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/interface-localization-to-german)
>   [How to deal with diacritics in tags?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58/how-to-deal-with-diacritics-in-tags)

I just tried to use "Übersetzung" as a tag, but the umlaut ü is not recognized and transformed to the letter u. Shouldn't umlauts be allowed on a site on German language?

Answer (score 0):

Ich würde sie hingegen sogar gerne in meiner deutschen Muttersprache abschaffen, aber auf mich hört ja keiner.

Es geht technisch einfach nicht.

Comment: Was geht technisch nicht?

Comment: Umlaute in tags

Comment: Warum, hat SE keine Unicode-Unterstützung?

Comment: Ich vermute mal, weil die ursprünglichen Seiten fast ausschließlich English verwenden. Und Englisch läßt sich beneidenswert einfach mit den 128 Zeichen des ASCII Zeichensatzes ausdrücken. Die nicht englischen Seiten sind sicher neuere Entwicklungen und machen nur einen kleinen Teil des Angebotes aus. Ich fürchte das hat einfach eine zu geringe Priorität.

Comment: 2003 ist ja auch schon ein paar Jährchen her ;) http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: The adequate site to ask for such changes is http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ where you can propose such technical changes. It is the meta site for all stackexchange sites.

Comment: @swegi in der Tat, nein. Die SO-Plattform wurde leider nur für englischen Gebrauch angelegt, volle internationale Unterstützung kommt erst noch. Siehe [Localization: The state of the nation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82176)