# Löschung von "überflüssigen" Tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Es gibt in "German Language" zurzeit die enorme Anzahl von 424 tags. Von diesen wurden 152 (also 36 %) noch keiner einzigen Frage zugeordnet. Eine ganze Reihe weiterer tags sind außerdem nur sehr selten verwendet worden.

Aufgrund der hohen Zahl von fast 16.000 Fragen gehe ich davon, dass die nicht verwendeten tags obsolet sind. Ich schlage daher eine "Aufräumaktion" zur Löschung dieser tags vor.

Comment: Was ist der Schaden, die Tags zu behalten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Die allermeisten – wenn nicht alle – Tags mit null Fragen sind gemergte [Tag-Synonyme](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms), insbesondere deutschsprachige Tags, die auf ihr englisches Pendant verweisen.
  Zum Beispiel [fragewoerter](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fragewoerter)→[interrogatives](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interrogatives): Wenn jemand, versucht, eine Frage mit [fragewoerter](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fragewoerter) zu taggen, wird dies automatisch durch [interrogatives](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interrogatives) ersetzt. Diese tags erfüllen einen Zweck und ich sehe nicht, wie sie irgendwen stören.
- Tags mit null Fragen, die keine Synonyme sind, werden täglich automatisch gelöscht. Hier gibt es nichts für uns zu tun.
- Tags mit wenigen Fragen können dennoch sinnvoll sein, um von denjenigen beobachtet zu werden, die sich für das jeweilige Thema interessieren. Wichtig ist eher, dass die Tags klar umrissen sind und leicht auffindbar für diejenigen, die Fragen über das jeweilige Thema stellen. Zum Beispiel habe ich [blackletter](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blackletter) abonniert.

Das heißt nicht, dass alle kleinen Tags sinnvoll sind; es gibt sicher Tags, die Synonyme größerer Tags sind oder schlecht umrissen oder nutzlos (weil sie niemals jemand abonnieren würde). Aber ich sehe keinen Grund, pauschal kleine Tags zu löschen.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Geschehen.

Comment: Ich habe noch Nachfragen. Ist es für Dich in Ordnung, wenn ich sie als Update zur Frage bringe oder wäre Dir eine neue Frage lieber?

Comment: @PaulFrost: Hängt von den Nachfragen ab. Im Zweifelsfall ist ein Kommentar auf die Antwort mit Klarstellungswünschen das Sinnvollste. Wenn es jedoch richtig große Fragen sind, kann auch eine neue Frage besser sein.

Comment: Okay. 1. Ist folgendes korrekt: Deutsche Tags sollten also nur als Synonyme auftauchen und mit 0 Anworten verknüpft sein. Es gibt einige Ausnahmen (umlaut, eszett, kurrent, duden, sein-or-haben, heidegger, suetterlin), die in der Sache begründet keinen englischen Primär-Tag haben. 2. Deutsche Tags werden oft ohne Umlaute geschrieben (Ausnahmen: uebersetzung und ubersetzung, graezismus und grazismus, fragewoerter und frageworter, aufzaehlung, anfuehrungszeichen, suetterlin und sutterlin). Ist das so beabsichtigt? Besonders verwirrend bei "falle".

Comment: 3. Gibt es eine Liste, in der man auf einen Blick sehen kann, welche Tags Synonyme welcher Primärtags sind?

Comment: 4. Und hier noch einige Fehler: Die Tags swiss-german und schweizerdeutsch sind keine Synonyme. Ebenso difference und unterschied.

Comment: @PaulFrost: 1. Im Wesentlichen, [ja](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/2594). Nebenbei ist [sein-or-haben] sehr wohl Englisch, sonst wäre es [sein-oder-haben]. 2. Ich sehe gerade zwar keine technische Notwendigkeit, sowohl [fragewoerter] als auch [frageworter] zu haben, aber eines der beiden muss sein, da Umlaute in Tags nicht möglich sind. [Hier](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/58/2594) ist eine alte Diskussion dazu. Wenn man die Tags wirklich nutzt, zeigt einem das System ja die Kurzbeschreibung an und es sollte solche Missverständnisse beseitigen – wenn man sie denn liest.

Comment: Sollte man dann nicht konsequent ae statt ä usw. schreiben? Oder meinetwegen beide Varianten ae/ a usw. gleichzeitig führen wie bei uebersetzung und ubersetzung?

Comment: @PaulFrost: 3. [Ja](https://german.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms). 4. Behoben. Falls Du weitere solche offensichtlichen Fälle siehst, flagge gerne eine beliebige betroffene Frage, dann können wir Moderatoren das schnell beheben. Es gibt zwar auch ein Synonymvorschlagssystem, aber das ist nicht wirklich brauchbar.

Comment: *Sollte man dann nicht konsequent ae statt a usw. schreiben?* – Ich weiß jetzt nicht, was besser für die automatisch vorgeschlagenen Tags ist und ob es einen Vorteil hat, beide zu haben. Wenn Du möchtest, kannst Du das ja gerne mal experimentell herausfinden und einen entsprechend Vorschlag in einer getrennten Meta-Frage einreichen.

Comment: Und ein letztes: Der Tag "litterature" als Synyonym von "literature" sollte gelöscht werden. "litterature" ist echt litter.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Geschehen.

Comment: Und noch einer: Zu *adjektiv* gibt es 5 Fragen. Sollte Synonym zu *adjectives* sein.