# Which language to use in tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which language should tags be in?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/which-language-should-tags-be-in)

I just skimmed through our current tag list and found, that all but **falle** currently are in English.

I propose to use English tags in the first place.

I'm not sure if German synonyms are possible. I guess that is a technical question i.e. better posed at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

And please give a good English translation for **falle**. I think it is a very important tag.

Is it **pitfall** ?

Comment: See also: [Which language should tags be in?](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/7/which-language-should-tags-be-in)