# Tag synonym requests

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

> Related: [Which language to use in tags?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/which-language-to-use-in-tags)

If the consensus is to use english-language tags, I suggest the following tag synonyms be created by whoever can create them (Mods? Community managers?) for automatic translation.

German/English synonym tag > English master tag

- [rechtschreibung](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rechtschreibung) > [spelling](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling) done
- [neue-rechtschreibung](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neue-rechtschreibung) > [reformed-orthography](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reformed-orthography) done
- [uebersetzung](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uebersetzung) > [translation](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) done
- [ubersetzung](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubersetzung) > [translation](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) done - **no unmlauts in tags**
- [orthographie](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthographie) > [orthography](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography) done
- [merkhilfe](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merkhilfe) > [mnemonics](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mnemonics) done
- `Merktechnik`=> `mnemonics` **rejected** (we should not synonymize unused tags)
- `Eselsbrücke`=> `mnemonics` **rejected** (we should not synonymize unused tags)
- `Mnemotechnik`=> `mnemonics` **rejected** (we should not synonymize unused tags)

Add new tags to this list or write a separate answer to suggest tag synonyms.

Comment: `trennbare-verben` => `separable-verbs`

Comment: @tim which markup do you use to generate the background in the comment? Looks really better than just bold

Comment: @bernd backticks: ``

Comment: But @bernd you haven't seen the coolest feature yet: `<kbd>`!  Doesn't work in comments though, sadly

Comment: Thanks. Next time I try format as code, to see what it does here - LOL

Comment: Ubersetzung geht aber nun nicht. No. What is Ubersetzung?