# Let’s create or improve tag wikis – but how?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

We already have quite a few nice [tags](https://german.stackexchange.com/tags) for classifying questions to make them better searchable.

But not all of them have a tag wiki, and some existing tag wikis are not really good. There is still some work to be done and 2 reputation to be earned for users who have not yet gained the [Trusted User privilege](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).

What format do we want the tag wikis to be in? Which information should be displayed when hovering over the tag or selecting a tag on creating a question?

Comment: What I am interested in is whether or not people read the info page. We talked about that yesterday, but what do other think? Do we need to add more context in the about field? If yes, what should we write there. More information about the tag itself? Suggestions, e.g. example quesions, how to use this tag? Reference to other similar tags? Currently we have mixed up the content. Sometimes we even have German translation, sometimes not.

Comment: @Em1: this should **really** be an answer, as we need to discuss this here. Only from an answer you get what others think ;)

Comment: What is the procedure for turning a newly created tag into a synonym pointing to an existing tag? Someone created <kbd>word-origin</kbd> and I would like to make it a synonym pointing to <kbd>etymology</kbd>.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel: it's this meta thread where you are welcome to post tag synonym requests: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/107/tag-synonym-requests. For now I created the synonym you requested. Thank you for finding this :)

Comment: @EugeneSeidel: also see here: http://german.stackexchange.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make sure... the standard way for suggesting tag synonyms seems to be designed for proposing a new tag as synonym for an existing tag but not for turning an existing tag into a synonym, which is what I wanted.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel: it should turn to a synonym as soon as it had enough votes. This would be in 10 - 20 years time, roughly estimated ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As from the following meta discussion we had consent that tags should be in English but synonymized to the German counterpart if applicable.

- [Which language should tags be in?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/which-language-should-tags-be-in)

Therefore we may also want to write the tag wikis in English. However it would be nice to have the German translation appearing first in the wiki when hovering over it. As examples see

[grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar)
[formality](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formality)
[pronouns](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronouns)
[swabian](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swabian)

This would ease choosing the appropriate tag for people who are not sure on the English counterpart of a German expression. Ideally this could further be eased by combining with a German tag synonym pointing to the English master tag.

For suggesting a tag synonym in case we have not yet gained the reputation needed to do so we may add an answer to the following post:

- [Tag synonym requests](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/tag-synonym-requests)

The tag wiki excerpt appearing when hovering over a tag should stay short to make it quickly readable. In the following formatted wiki we may give longer explanations or links to relevant web pages.

Comment: IIRC in the question writing view, you will see the synonymized tags in the tag chosing window that shows up when you start typing

Comment: @Vogel612: that's true... if we had this in the Wiki it will additionaly confirm a user had chosen the tag they meant.

Answer (score 2):

People are also interested in reading the full info tag, i.e. the about field.

We should provide more information in this field. Currently we have a mixed-up content. Some of them provide example questions, other provide alternatives tags. Sometimes the info box is in English and German, sometimes only English. We need to improve these information.

(Note: If this answer gets a lot of upvotes we should decide in a second step which content needs to be provided.)

Comment: Feel free to offer an answer for each variant so that we can see which gets the most upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if Takkat and @Em1 and anyone else interested could have a look at [mnemonics](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mnemonics) that I just created:

> Mnemotechnik nennt man einen Merkspruch, eine Eselsbrücke oder Merkhilfe, die das Einprägen von Fakten erleichtern sollen. Quelle: Wikipedia
>   A mnemonic or mnemonic device is any learning technique that aids information retention. Source: Wikipedia

As per the discussion above, I made it bilingual but with German appearing first in both the tag wiki and the tag wiki excerpt. Please let me know if this is an acceptable template. I may want to do a bunch of them this weekend, got my eyes set on that Research Assistant badge ;)

Comment: Any resource from where a tag wiki was copied should be quoted as such, which was done here. Personally I prefer genuine own content because we do not really know where the Wikipedia content was copied from. But then I understand, that we do not have to reinvent the wheel here. Bilingual wikis are great.

Comment: Get the badge. - I remember when talking to @Takkat a while ago he mentioned that it's may be a good idea to keep the text as short as possible so that it fits into the small popup. Also we began to start with the translation, and adding a short description behind a proper translation. I think it would be fine if we'd keep a consistent style for all tags. - Besides that, I'd appreciate every effort taken into some clean up of the jungle of tags. Go ahead :)

Comment: I do not consider this a good tag-wiki excerpt and in particular not a well-chosen example. The tag wiki itself is not well readable, unecessarily long and focusses too much on explaining the word behind the tag, which is necessary in this particular case, but not in general.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Takkat’s answer](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/471/2594), I want to remark that we should focus on helping users to understand what a tag is about, not on explaining the word behind the tag.

The purpose of tag wikis is to explain the usage of a tag. Thus focus on such things as:

- To what questions should this tag be applied?
- To what questions should this tag not be applied?
- Are there related tags that may be better suited?

In most cases we do not need to educate the user what the word behind a tag means. For example most users know what a verb is and in the rare case that they don’t, there are better places to explain it to them, in particular Wikipedia. The exception are highly technical terms such as [expletiva](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expletiva), but even here a short description usually suffices.

Finally, remember that the excerpt usually suffices to store all the information required for most purposes and you only need the actual wiki if the usage of a tag needs extensive information or if you want to give guidance on how to ask a good question in a given tag or list good example questions.