# Präteritum or preterite tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We currently have one question in [praeteritum](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/praeteritum) and one in [prateritum](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prateritum). Would the English tag [preterite](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preterite) be an adequate translation?

Answer (score 1):

**Preterite** is a good translation. Whether to use that or **Praeteritum** as the main tag depends on [which language it's decided to have main tags in](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/37).

However I would say **imperfect** is the English term that I encountered most when learning German, [even though that isn't strictly correct](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,344448,00.html). I've also seen **simple past** used to teach German to English speakers.

For the sake of learners encountering these terms, they should be synonyms. The tag wiki would be a good place to explain the proper/preferred terminology.

Comment: So which one should be the main tag?

Comment: If [primary tags are to be in English](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/7/37), **preterite**, as it is the most precise translation of the "official" German term.

Comment: +1 for *simple past* being used. I just sat a grammar test, and that is the terminology used.