# Should and can we make more clear to newcomers that we are bilingual?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred, language, design

The first few things a newcomer is likely to read on this site are:

> **German Language beta**
>   German Language Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for speakers of German wanting to discuss the finer points of the language and translation. It's 100% free, no registration required.

Should and can we make more clear that questions can be asked and answered in both, English and German, here, so that we attract more native speakers with questions about the German language?

I am not talking about a [complete interface localisation](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/interface-localization-to-german), only about something like making the name and the description of the site bilingual.

## Update

Changing the whole welcome text is not easily possible. However, we can change the part describing the target audience, i.e., what follows the *for*. I will start a Meta discussion on this shortly.

Comment: ja, ein [*About*](http://german.stackexchange.com/about) auf Deutsch wäre gar nicht schecht.

Comment: just on a sidenote, this seems to be a real problem: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14123419#14123419

Comment: Do we need a consensus or is a compromise with majority sufficient?

Comment: @userunknown: What would be the difference given the current votes? Right now, we most of all need this to be realisable. I am trying to find out what’s possible.

Comment: A consensus means, that everybody has to agree. If one person disagrees, you don't have a consensus.

Comment: @userunknown: And so far, everybody who voted on this agreed – I do not see a single downvote. So, there is no difference in this case. Unfortunately, realising this seems to be problematic. [More on this in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24139881#24139881) or after a while on Meta.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update**: As of Nov. 24th, 2015, the welcome text has been changed as per the follow up thread to this question, which can be found [here](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1008/).

---

I think it would help attracting native speakers and expert questions, if we had a bilingual title and description. I thus propose:

> **German Language / Deutsche Sprache beta**
>
> German Language Stack Exchange is a question-and-answer site for speakers and learners of German wanting to discuss the finer points of the language and translation – in English or German. It's 100% free, no registration required.
>
> *Stack Exchange – Deutsche Sprache* ist eine Seite für Fragen und Antworten, auf der Lerner und Kenner Feinheiten der deutschen Sprache sowie Übersetzungen diskutieren können – auf Deutsch oder Englisch. Diese Seite ist vollkommen kostenlos und bedarf keiner Anmeldung.

Comment: Ich habe zur Sicherheit noch eine explizite Erwähnung der Sprachen hinzugefügt.

Comment: Are you sure that "Stack-Exchange" should be masculine? I know it's a newly coined term anyway in German, but the second sentence sounds kind of weird if it starts with "Er". How about repeating "die Seite" there? i.e. "Die Seite ist vollkommen ... etc".

Comment: @MathiasMüller: No, I am not sure, but everything else feels weird. Concerning the second sentence, you were right. Also, feel free to edit and improve such things yourself.

Comment: Warum nicht einfach "Deutsche Sprache Stack Exchange"? Das wäre der Titel der Seite; es ist ja nicht so, als wäre "Stack Exchange" eine neuer Typ von Ding.

Comment: @Raphael: Die englische Konstruktion behandelt es zumindest so und ist meines Wissens auch im Englischen recht ungewöhnlich (für Eigennamen). *Deutsche-Sprache-Stack-Exchange* fände ich auch nicht weniger klobig. Einzige Parallele, die mir einfällt, ist *Rechtsreib-Duden,* was auch nur so wirklich funktioniert, da *Duden* kaum noch als Eigenname empfunden wird. Vielleicht als Vergleich mit mehreren Wörtern auf beiden Seiten: Was fändest Du besser, »(Das) Unsere-Erde-Was-ist-Was hat 76 Seiten.« oder »Das Was-ist-Was Unsere Erde hat 76 Seiten?«

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Tatsächlich "*Was ist Was -- Unsere Erde* hat 76 Seiten", also den Titel als Eigennamen verwenden. (Randnotiz: "Deutsche Sprache" wird selten benutzt, oder? Meistens sagt man einfach "[Das] Deutsch[e]".)

Comment: @Raphael: Also »*Stack Exchange – Deutsche Sprache* ist eine Frage-und-Antwort-Seite …«?

Comment: Wäre mir lieber. Also, mal davon abgesehen, dass der offizielle Titel "X Stack Exchange" ist. Und als nächstes sprechen wir über "Frage-und-Antwort-Seite" -- wäh! Schlicht: "eine Seite für Fragen und Antworten über X, auf der...". Drittens sei der Hinweis auf "Lerner" vs. "Lernende" gestattet. Ich hänge dieser Grammatikverdrehung nicht an, aber immer mehr bestehen drauf...