# Still unchanged summary in the StackExchange site overview page

Tags: feature-request, bug

In the [overview page for all S.E. sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name)<sup>*</sup> we are still listed with our initial site summary:

> Q&A for speakers of German wanting to discuss the finer points of the language and translation

<sup>*site mods can not edit this page</sup>

We changed this site summary [some years ago](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1008/please-vote-on-new-wordings-of-our-welcome-text-description-of-the-target-audi) to better reflect that we are bilingual, and that beginners are welcome too. Since then we welcome users with:

> Bilingual question-and-answer site for speakers of all levels who want to share and increase their knowledge of the German language.

Apparently we forgot the site overview text which should also display the new wording. To be consistent with the other sites it may be shortened to

> Bilingual Q&A for speakers of all levels who want to share and increase their knowledge of the German language.